# Why am i getting undefined of my constant?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to make a login functionality with nodejs and reactjs.
I have a key in my initial state object called isAuthenticated which is false at first, and the value changes wether the login was successful or not.

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import  userSlice  from '../reducers/auth/authSlice'


const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userSlice
  }
})

export default store
```

This is my reducer:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import setAuthToken from '../../utils/setAuthToken';

import axios from 'axios';

const initialState = {
    token: localStorage.getItem('item'),
    isAuthenticated: false,
    loading: true,
    user: null,
    error: null
}

export const loadUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/loadUser',
  async ({ rejectWithValue }) => {

    if(localStorage.token){
      setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
    }

    try {
      const res = axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/auth');
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
)

export const registerUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/registerUser',
  async (newUser, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      };
      const body = JSON.stringify(newUser);
      const response = await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:3000/api/users',
        body,
        config
      );
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);


export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk('auth/login', async ({ email, password }, { dispatch, rejectWithValue }) => {
  const body = { email, password };

  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  try {
    const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/auth', body, config);

    dispatch(loadUser());
    console.log(body)
    return res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    return rejectWithValue(err.response.data);
  }
});

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [registerUser.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = null;
    },
    [registerUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = null;
      
    },
    [registerUser.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
    [loadUser.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = null;
    },
    [loadUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
      state.user = action.payload;
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = false;
    },
    [loadUser.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
      state.error = action.payload;

    },
    [loginUser.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = null;
    },
    [loginUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.token = localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
      state.loading = false;
      state.user = action.payload.user;
    },
    [loginUser.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    }
  }
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const {  } = userSlice.actions


export default userSlice.reducer
```

And this is my component that receives isAuthenticated prop from my slice:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { loginUser } from '../reducers/auth/authSlice';

//Material UI
import {Grid, Container, Box, Button, FormControl, InputLabel, Input, FormHelperText } from '@mui/material'

function Login({ isAuthenticated }) {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ 
    email: '',
    password: ''
    
  });

  console.log(isAuthenticated)

  const { email, password } = formData;

  const onChange = e => setFormData({
      ...formData, [e.target.name]:e.target.value
  });

  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(loginUser({email, password}))
    
  }

  

    return (
    <Container>
        <Box p={4}>
            <Grid container  >
                <form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)} >
                    <Grid item md={12}>
                        <FormControl>
                            <InputLabel htmlFor="email">Email</InputLabel>
                            <Input 
                            id='email' 
                            type='email' 
                            name='email'
                            value={email}
                            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                            />
                            <FormHelperText>Insert your email</FormHelperText>
                        </FormControl>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item md={12}>    
                        <FormControl>
                            <InputLabel htmlFor="password">Password</InputLabel>
                            <Input 
                            id="password" 
                            type='password' 
                            name='password'
                            value={password}
                            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                            />
                            <FormHelperText>Insert your password (must have at least 6 characters)</FormHelperText>
                        </FormControl>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item md={12}>    
                        <Button type='submit' variant="contained" color="primary">
                            Login
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </form>
            </Grid>
        </Box>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Login
```

As you can see in the slice in the `loginUser`function i log the information i am passing through the form and being received by my method. But for some reason the value of `isAuthenticated` which i am going to check its value to render different things and functionalities is at every moment `undefined`.

Why is my prop undefined? Am i passing the prop wrongly? Because the initialState is false and should change to true if it is fulfilled.

Comment: You didn't show any code that would put that slice data in the prop. Do you assume that would happen automatically?

Comment: I am importing the slice in my component and using the isAuthenticated prop from the slice and passing it to my component. I am new to redux so i have some troubles. @phry What do you mean by puting the slice data in the prop?

Answer (score 0):

Importing the slice in the component file doesn't magically make it appear as a prop. A prop appears when you call a component with a prop, like `<Login isAuthenticated={...} />`

You are probably not doing that, or you wouldn't ask this question.

Data from the store could also appear as a prop if you were using the legacy `connect`/`mapStateToProps` method, but you didn't show code, so I will assume that you don't do that either (and nowadays, you also shouldn't).

Apart from those two, there is no reason Redux state would ever be in your props. You have to explicitly access that Redux state, by using the `useSelector` hook.

That would look like

```js
const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => state.user.isAuthenticated)
```

in your component. No props.

As a sidenote, the `extraReducers` object notation you are using here is not recommended any more and deprecated. You are probably following an outdated tutorial. I would highly recommend you to follow [the official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) instead.